# Proof of Lusin-Novikov

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-set-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Does anyone have a reference for the proof of following Theorem:

(Lusin - Novikov) 
Let X,Y be two standard Borel space and $E \subset X \times Y$ a Borel subset. We assume that $\forall x \in X$ the fiber $\pi^{-1}(x) \cap E$ is countable where
$\pi: X \times Y \to X$. Then there is a countable partition $E=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{E_n}$ where $E_n$ is Borel for all n such that $\pi |_{E_n} : E_n \to X$ is injective.

In the literature it is referred to as Lusin-Novikov Theorem, but a google 
search of this does not reveal any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, Theorem 18.10.

Comment: You know of any others that have online PDF access?

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias: I do not, sorry.